# changing date format in to another in mongo db

Tags: javascript, jquery, codeigniter

I have a datepicker in my view page. When inserting the date into the table in this format : "Friday 20 July 2018". But I want to insert the date in normal fromat(dd-mm-YY)

view page:-

```
`<script>
function create_challenges(){ 
          if(! $("form#create_challenge").valid()) return false;
          if($('select[name="activity"]').val() ==0 && $('input[name="custom_activity"]').val() =="")
            { alert("Please select an activity/ add a new activity");return false;}
          $("#btn_create").prop('disabled', true);

          var formdata = $("#create_challenge").serialize()+ "&filenames="+ file_names.toString();

          $.ajax({
                url: "<?= base_url('') ?>"+"api/web/challenge/create",
                type: "POST",
                dataType : 'json', // data type
                data : formdata, // post data 
                success: function(data){

                        alert("Challenge Created Successfully");
                        redirect_url= "<?= base_url('') ?>"+"challenge/list_challenges";
                        /*var challenger_form = $('<form action="' + redirect_url + '" method="post">' +
                                      '<input type="text" name="challenge_id" value="' + data['data'] + '" />' +
                                      '</form>');
                        $('body').append(challenger_form);
                        challenger_form.submit();*/

                },
                error: function(){ $("#btn_create").prop('disabled', false); }          
            });


    }
</script>`
```

in this way am posting my data in to the database.

Then how can I convert ("Friday 20 July 2018") into (dd/mm/YY") this format.`enter code here`

Comment: Try moment.js https://momentjs.com/

Comment: pls always response to the answers by giving some comments or ,if it helps you, by marking it as green and upvoting, it is the best way to thanks all the programmers

Answer (score 0):

**Hope this will help you :**

In your controller's `create` method ,

**First**: use ci date helper's `nice_date` method  like this :

```
//in autoload.php add date helper like this 
$autoload['helper'] = array('date');

 //in create method use like this 
$date = 'Friday 20 July 2018';
echo nice_date($date, 'Y-m-d').PHP_EOL;
echo nice_date($date, 'd/m/Y').PHP_EOL;
```

Output :

```
2018-07-20
20/07/2018
```

For more : https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/date_helper.html

**Second** : use `date_create_from_format` to convert date from specific format

```
$date = 'Friday 20 July 2018';

$mydate = date_create_from_format('l d F Y',$date);
echo date_format($mydate,'d/m/Y');
//echo date_format($mydate,'m-d-Y');
```

Output :

```
20/07/2018
```

Working demo : https://eval.in/1039544

For more : http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php